# Why can I add an object of a class to a LinkedList of another class?

Tags: java

I have a class as this one:

```
public class One {
    private int idOne;
    private String nameOne;
    //Getter and Setter
}
```

And another class that extends One:

```
public class Two extends One {
    private String moreThings;
    private String example;
    //Getter and Setter
}
```

Then have `LinkedList<One> myList = new LinkedList<>();`

I dont understand why I can add `Two` objects to that list if I specified that the list was going to have `One` objects `LinkedList<One>`. Example:

```
LinkedList<One> myList = new LinkedList<>();

Two t1 = new Two();
Two t2 = new Two();

myList.add(t1);
myList.add(t2);
```

That is cool but just dont know why can I do that.

Comment: Because it `extends One`. You *did* wrote `extends One`, what was the reason for that?

Comment: Because polymorphism.  Every instance of `Two` is also an instance of `One`.  This would also work, for example, if you use a `LinkedList<Object>`.

Comment: FAMOUS QUOTE **dog will always be an animal ,but you cannot say that animal will always be a dog**

Comment: Exactly what those three ^ said. for more explanation read on OOP

Comment: For such relationships, it's always recommended to think in real world objects, rather than abstract names("One","Two","myList" etc). Just like nobalG did with the dog/animal analogy.

Comment: Pretty good, you did solve my doubts. The answer is in these comments but non of you wrote an Stackoverflow answer. Please do it @nobalG with the explanation of polymorphism so I could choose yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your problem as a real world example,Let you have a class `Animal`, having methods like  `running()` ,`eating()`, `drinking()` etc.Now your class will look like

```
class Animal
{
  public void running()
  {
    //some code
  }

  public void eating()
  {
    //some code
  }

  public void drinking()
  {
    //some code
  }
}
```

[image]

---

Let you have two other classes `Dog` and `Cat`, as they are type of animal so they can extend `Animal` class.
So it will be completely valid to say that

```
Animal animalObject=new Dog();  // a dog is a type of animal
or
Animal animalObject=new Cat();  //cat is a type of animal
or
Dog dogObject=new Dog();   //Nothing special
or
Cat catObject=new Cat();    //Nothing special
```

However ,Following are invalid

```
Dog dogObject=new Animal();
or
Cat catObject=new Animal();
```

because (read that quote again.) and Do give an [eye to this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm).. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `One` and `Two` try thinking about it using the class names `Animal` and `Cat`.

You declared that your List should hold `Animal` objects, so it's not surprising that it will accept a `Cat`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `One extends Two`.  This is called polymorphism.

You could not however do `List<two>` then add objects of type `One` to a list of type `Two`.

Object of type `two` has atleast everything `one` does and possibly more that is why it works.

Comment: i'm hoping you are going to extend your answer cus' if it stays like this i will have to downvote u

Answer (score 0):

Since the class Two is a subset of class One ; which means every Two is One but One is not necessarily Two. Referring to earlier answers Cat(Two) is a subset of Animal(One)

In your case you are initializing a linked list of Object One(Animal) and than adding Object Two(Cat) in it which makes sense because Two(Cat) is One(Animal).

But if you were to go other way for e.g; Adding One(Animal) to the linked list of Two(Cat);

It would have given you an error.